# Lemme itô and Martingale

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes, finance, martingales

I want to to find values of $a$, $b$ such that the process:

$$e^{W_{t}^2+at+b\int_\limits{0}^{t}W_{s}^2\,ds}$$
be a  martingale

Could you please help me do that

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $X_t = W_t^2 + at + b\int_0^t W_s^2\, ds$, so that
  $$dX_t =  (1 + a + bW_t^2)\, dt + 2W_t\, dW_t$$
and
  $$d[X,X]_t = 4W_t^2\, dt.$$

Using Ito's lemma, we get
  $$d[e^{X_t}] = e^{X_t}\, dX_t + \frac{1}{2} e^{X_t} d[X, X]_t
    = e^{X_t}\bigl((1 + a + (b + 2)W_t^2)\,dt + 2W_t\, dW_t\bigr).$$
For $e^{X_t}$ to be a martingale, the drift term must vanish, i.e., $a = -1$ and $b = -2$.

Comment: From where come the (one 1) in  dXt=(1+a+bW2t)dt+2WtdWt

Comment: and how did you calculate the crochet d[X,X]t=4Wt^2dt

Comment: and how did you calculate the crochet d[X,X]t=4Wt^2dt

Comment: @denek The $1$ comes from $d(W_t^2) = 2W_t dW_t + \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 d[W,W]_t$. The calculation of $d[X,X]_t$ is standard: you can formally compute $dX_t\,dX_t$ by substituting the expression for $dX_t$ and using the stylized facts that $dt\, dt = dt\, dW_t = 0$ and $dW_t\, dW_t = dt$.